# Custom B2B iOS app distribution in the country not available to use volume purchase program (VPP)

Tags: ios, b2b

I'd like to distribute a custom B2B iOS app privately to my customers. It seems that the best solution is to distribute the app in enterprise app store for customers having a volume purchase program (VPP) account for now. However, my customers locate in China the country not available to use VPP yet. Is there a chance to get another solution to distribute a custom B2B iOS app to customers? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: Finally, we decide to pivot to a B2C app with account management and to distribute it in the  iTunes app store.

Comment: @GreenerChen what exactly do you mean? and which developer program you used? I am having similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently spoken to a member of the Apple Developer Relations Team on exactly this question. Their policy is that if an app that is supposed to be distributed through Custom B2B + VPP, but the country is not available in the program yet, this app can be submitted to the Public App Store and will not be rejected for being internal/enterprise targeted.

Another user also answered this over at Ask Different: [VPP app for business worldwide distribution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150510/vpp-app-for-business-worldwide-distribution)

Alternatively if you are only targeting employees, you could distribute the app via the [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/) through inhouse deployment. This works with either MDM or a [custom download page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204460).